# Articles in captions (tables, pictures, etc.)

Tags: articles, titles

I have some awful problems with editing picture and table captions in a paper I'm working on. Maybe some native speaker could give me a hand. One of the captions is for example:

Figure 14. The dynamics of crime in X. **A** causal chain.

It's under a diagram with which I want to explain the dynamics of crime in X - the diagram presents a causal chain.

Should it be "A causal chain" or just "Causal chain"?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question about the dynamics of crime in X for anyone to be sure. Is 'a causal chain' supposed to *illustrate* the dynamics of crime in X, or *is it* the dynamics of crime in X?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but I added some information to make it clearer. The caption is under a diagram presenting a causal chain. Something like this: http://labspace.open.ac.uk/file.php/8342/t172_1_011.jpg

Comment: The question I'm asking is whether the causal chain is a *subset* of the dynamics of crime in X (being perhaps just one causal chain out of several), or whether it represents the *totality* of the dynamics of crime in X.

Comment: The totality I guess. It represents my interpretation of the empirical process I analyze in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

OK then -- following your clarifications, I suggest these possibilities:

> Figure 14. The dynamics of crime in X: a causal chain.

(As a typical example of such a chain)

> Figure 14. The dynamics of crime in X: the causal chain.

(Refers exclusively to the causal chain in X).

Comment: Interesting. After your questions I was sure, you would say: without an article or with "the".

Comment: I've refined my thoughts -- see above.

Answer (score 0):

To be clearer, state the relationship between "crime in X" and "causal chain" in your caption, and use a full sentence. For example:

> Figure 14. The dynamics of crime in X represent a causal chain.

or

> Figure 14. A causal chain showing the dynamics of crime in X.